# How can i seperate calculated values from auto generated JPA entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, netbeans, calculated-field

I created my JPA entities via reverse engineering in netbeans and i also added some calculated values to my entities like; i have `name` and `surname` fields in the `users` table and i created a method in `user` entity like

```
public String getDisplayName()
{
    return name + " " + surname;
}
```

And i have several of this and in addition i've overridden some superclass methods like `compareTo()`, `toString()`

What i want to do is to seperate these methods so when i regenerate the entities i'll not have to add these methods manually again and again.
As i know, you can not seperate a class to multiple files in java.
I tried inheritance as well but i'm not sure what is going to be the best practice.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to share some code between 2 classes, there are only 2 possibilities:

- Inheritance, where the shared code is delegated to an abstract class and the concrete implementations extend it. If you use it in JPA, you have to be aware that data bases (generally) do not support such approach and you have to design the mapping (https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/).
- Composition, where the shared code is encapsulated in a separate class used as a field type in concrete implementation.

Example of the latter:

```
@Entity
public class PersonalData {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return name + " " + surname;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class User {
    private PersonalData data;
}
```

Additionally, to avoid boilerplate code creation, you can use Lombok: https://projectlombok.org/